# centos/apache/php/mongodb - can't get this to work together

Tags: docker, docker-compose

It's been a few days since I've been trying to get docker container up and running, and always something goes wrong.

I need (mostly) LAMP stack, only instead MySQL -> mongoDb.

Of course I started by looking on docker hub and trying to compose some image from others. Googled after configs. Simplest one couldn't go past the stage of setting MONGODB_ADMIN_USER and MONGODB_ADMIN_PASSWORD and always returned with code 1, though mentioned variables were set in yml.

I tried to start with just centos/mongodb image, install apache, php and whatnot, commit it, and work on my own image, but without kernel it's hard to properly install and run apache within docker container.

So i tried once more, found promising project here: https://github.com/akhomy/docker-compose-lamp
but can't attach to the container, can't run localhost with default settings, though apparently composing stage goes ok.

Has anyone of You, by chance, working set of docker files / docker-compose?
Or some helpful hint? Really, looks like a straightforward task, take two images from docker hub, make docker-compose.yml, run docker-compose up, case closed. I can't wrap my head around this :|

Answer (score 1):

Docker approach is not to put all services in one container but to have a single container for a single service. All Docker tools are aligned to this.

For your LAMP stack to start, you just have to download `docker-compose`, create `docker-compose.yml` file with 3 services defined and run `docker-compose up`

Docker compose is an orchestrating tool for containers, suited for single machine.

You need to have at least small tour over this tool, just for an example I provide sample config file:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  apache:
    image: bitnami/apache:latest
    .. here goes apache config ...
  db:
    image: mongo
    .. here goes apache config ...
  php:
    image: php
    .. here goes php config ...
```

After you start this with `docker-compose up` you will get network created automatically for you and all services will join it. They will see each other under their names (lets say to connect to database from php you will use `db` as host name).

To connect to this stuff from host PC, you will need to expose ports explicitly.

Comment: Yeah, that's more or less what I have been trying to do over the course of a few days lately. Always something is off. The closest I was, when this issue with MONGODB_ADMIN_PASSWORD came up and for the life of me I couldn't force it to read the config from yml file. Maybe the fact that it's windows machine doesn't help.